# BJT - finding Ic with two opposite voltages connected to base

Tags: bjt, negative-voltage

Here's a question from my homework:

> Find \$  I_C  \$ and \$  V_{CE}  \$ for the circuits below, assuming \$  |V_{BE}| = 0.7V  \$ and \$  \beta = 100  \$.
>
> [image: The BJT circuit. There are two voltage sources connected to the base: +15 V with a 470k resistor, and -15 V with a 1M resistor. Another voltage source of +15 V with a 6.8k resistor is connected to the collector.]

I understand circuit (a), but for (b), I don't understand how to incorporate the \$  -15V  \$ branch into calculation.

Below is my attempt:

> $$  R_{TH} = \frac {R_1 R_2} {R_1 + R_2} = 3.197 \times 10^5 \Omega  $$
>
> $$  V_{TH} = \frac {V_1 R_2 + V_2 R_1} {R_1 + R_2} = 5.408 V  $$
>
> $$  \therefore I_B = \frac{V_{TH} - V_{BE}} {R_{TH}} = 1.47 \times 10^{-5} A  $$
>
> $$  I_C = \beta I_B = (100) (4.69 \times 10^{-5}) =  1.47 mA $$

Edit: Thank you all so much for the helppppppppp~

Comment: Do you know the Thevenin's theory? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/471906/calculation-of-base-current-and-what-decides-the-current-through-collector-emitt/471923#471923

Comment: According to Kirchhoffs current law: Ib1=Ib+Ib2.

Comment: Thank you @G36 for the reference~

Comment: Thanks @LvW for pointing it out!

Comment: But I'm still quite confused about the -15V branch. Do I treat it like normal voltage/current but with an opposite sign?

Comment: Disconnect the base.  What is the voltage at the 2-resistor node?  What is the Thevenin-equivalent resistance?  Re-connect the base.

Comment: -15V means that the voltage at the lower side of 1M resistor is 15V lower than the reference voltage. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392010/how-to-find-voltage-based-on-reference-nodes/392063#392063

Comment: I see the mistake the base current is equal to \$I_B = \frac{V_{TH} - V_{BE}}{R_{TH}}\$

Comment: @G36 Ohhhh yes that's a careless mistake. Also thanks for helping me get my concept right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem

What is the Thevenin-equivalent voltage at the 2-resistor node?  Hint: Disconnect the base.

What is the Thevenin-equivalent resistance?

Re-connect the base.

Solve.