Determine the voltages Va and V1 for the circuit
I'm going through Boylestad 11th Edition and there is a question 37 b) on page 182 that I cannot get right. "Determine the voltages Va and V1 for the networks in Fig. 5.120."
So the second one, b), I cannot get.
Circuit as follows:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
So I drew the circuit like this.

simulate this circuit
Then I added the voltages up to get 14V. Then I used ohms law to get
$$I = \frac{V}{R}$$
$$2.25mA = \frac{14}{5500}$$
$$V1 = 0.0025 \times 2200 = 5.6V$$
Then I thought I would get Va simply by adding 10V onto (12-5.6) to get 16.4V.
But the book says the answer is: V1 = 12V and Va = 10V.
I am really not sure how to do these does anyone see where I went wrong?
thanks

You need to flip V3 voltage source to get -8V. Also, take a look here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392010/how-to-find-voltage-based-on-reference-nodes/392063#392063

That's awesome @G36 Thankyou.  You want to put that as an answer so I can tick it?

@Bucephalus You have a total of 30 V across the two resistors, 12 V across the left one and 18 V across the right one. But I'm guessing that you see this fact, now. The way I'd solve this is to move the 10 V source to the left, swapping it with R1. This means that the left voltage is now 12+10=+22 V, after adding the swapped 10 V supply with the +12 V left node. +22 - (-8) = 30 V total. So I can use that to get the current, just as you wrote.

So you did manage to get the correct answer now?

I did @G36 . The answers concur with the book now after flipping the voltage V3.

Thanks @periblepsis for showing me the trick of swapping the voltage V2 over.

You almost nailed it. All you need to do is to flip the V3 voltage source to get -8V with respect to GND.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
