Problems with understanding the potential and voltages in circut

I'm asked to find \$V_\text{out}\$. The solution suggests to find \$V_{C}\$ and calculate the voltage on R2 using voltage divider on R1 and R2.
My problem is understanding what does it mean finding voltage on a point.
I'm looking for a way to fully understand these type of questions, where there are no components in series or parallel (because of the \$V_\text{out}\$ "wire").

You would find $V_C$ with respect to ground (which is, in turn, assumed to be 0 V). The question says something about finding a voltage "on a point"?

"point" = "dot"= Node. Apply Norton equiv. to R's puts them in series RLC /w resonant Q .  Try again and refine question.

The point I mean is $V_\text{out}$.
Let me be more clear, I can understand the solution, but I dont really know why some parts are true. Like why  $V_\text{out}$ is the voltage on R2. I'm trying to develop a deep understanding

Take a look here it may help you https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/392010/how-to-find-voltage-based-on-reference-nodes/392063#392063
